# Mysterious disappearance of options from historical datasets

Tags: options, historical-data, option-strategies

I am in the process of analyzing historical options data, and I keep finding options that mysteriously disappear before they are due to expire. For example:

For the QQQ $69 Put,  
http://www.eoddata.com/stockquote/OPRA/QQQ140322P00069000.htm  
there is no data after 03/11/14

But the QQQ $70 Put, 
http://www.eoddata.com/stockquote/OPRA/QQQ140322P00070000.htm  
is fine.

It seems that all QQQ Puts with strike below $70 mysteriously disappears after 03/11/14, despite some of them having significant open interest.

I have found this in a dataset I obtained through another vendor as well.

What is the cause of these disappearances? Is it a data problem or were they halted trading for some reason?

Comment: @Downvoters and closevoters: Please give a reason and/or some ideas how to improve the question - thank you!

Comment: Can you please use readable dates! 03/11/14 could be 2003-11-14, 2014-11-03 or 2014-03-11.  I want to check with my vendor but I don't know what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data has definitely not disappeared, it's a problem with your vendor.

There has been a corporate action on 2014-02-27 and hence the strike prices have been adapted accordingly.  According to [Bloomberg bsym](http://bsym.bloomberg.com) your P69 (composite ID BBG004L7P7L6) became P68.63, and P70 (BBG004L7P8C4) became P69.63.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What vendor would you recommend as having the correct data?

Comment: If it's solely US single stock options you're after, try Market Data Express (http://www.marketdataexpress.com)

Comment: Do you have any experience with OptionMetrics? All I want is EOD bid/ask for US.

Comment: OptionMetrics handles corporate actions and links the options, so you can track the contract before and after such event.